# What chemical can cause such a fire?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, combustion

A friend of mine who thinks that she is under influence of black magic met an astrologer. The astrologer asked her to wear a t-shirt for three nights and then bring that to him. The astrologer then cut some lemons and rubbed them throughout the t-shirt. Then he poured some water on her hands and face; and asked her to keep the t-shirt on her palm. After about 15 minutes, the y-shirt caught fire and the astrologer dropped the rest of water to put the fire down.

I'm now wondering what chemical could cause this fire. I know that the water looked muddy. Would you please help me to find out what material was potentially used by the astrologer? I'm suspicious of the acid in the lemons and water which has been used, as well as body fat or sweat perhaps was on the t-shirt too. She was telling me that at first, smoke color was white but then it turned to black after the t-shirt caught fire. The smell of the fire was as bad as rotten meat.

Comment: Was an alcoholic smell around?

Comment: Not sure about alcoholic smell. I been told that was very bad smell seems a dead body smell

Comment: And here my  inner sceptic activates and a question arises: I don't see any proof here so how am I supposed know if you or your colleague didn't made it up? Even if it's not the case, then it was a trick and these are made to be hard to analyse and fool people. Therefore I don't see how it's supposed to be valid question.

Comment: Is this just a curiosity, where you believe the events can be explained by chemistry, but don't yet know the chemicals?  Or do you plan to accomplish something with this information?  Or are you worried about how long you can wear a shirt before drinking margaritas becomes hazardous? ;-)

Comment: Thanks any way for your attention. I don't know how shall I answer your curiosity to make you sure what I said is true and real. All I can tell you, even when I heard what's happened there, at the first I believed that should be some kind of mysterious power behind it, but soon after I come to my senses that should be explaining by chemistry. Chemistry ain't my field, and I just looking for some answer. Any way the astrologer asked for money now to complete the practice. That's why I'm looking for some logical answer to feed my own curiosity.

Comment: Magic tricks don't usually rely on exotic physics or chemistry, they just rely on the fact that humans have limited perceptive abilities. I'd personally guess that the guy had a hidden lighter somewhere before assuming there's some secret chemistry at play.

Answer (score 4):

[White phosphorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_phosphorus_munitions) can spontaneously ignite in air, and produces white smoke.

Some oils, like [linseed oil](https://www.dfes.wa.gov.au/safetyinformation/fire/fireinthehome/FireintheHomeFactsheets/DFES-Home-Fire-Safety-Info-Note-Linseed-Oil.pdf), on bunched-up cloth can also spontaneously combust.

Comment: The problem is we don't know what exactly he used. All I know is that after he rubbed cut lemons on cloths, and after about 15 minutes the cloths ignited. Perhaps it make sense to you that whatever trick it was, he done it perfectly without she realises what's going on.

Comment: All the clue that I have, the time of around 15 minutes and white smoke at the first of ignition as well as bad smell like a dead body smell. That's all I know. I'm not sure how long does it take for white phosphorus or linseed oil to ignite.

Comment: In meantime, in my point of view, this should be an old style alchemy that used by such people and passed generation to generation. I don't feel it's a new chemistry science.

Comment: @user59309 linseed oil soaked rag took 3 hours and 10 minutes in this experiment: http://abcnews.go.com/GMA/ConsumerNews/summer-safety-diy-dangers-linseed-oil/story?id=11328546 however, if the ambient temperature is high, it would take less time.

Comment: @user59309 "a small chunk of white phosphorus has been left exposed to air for about 15 minutes (which is not shown); the white phosphorus then spontaneously ignites, producing a brilliant" https://www.angelo.edu/faculty/kboudrea/demos/burning_phosphorus/burning_phosphorus.htm

Comment: @user59309 see "The Alchymist, In Search of the Philosopher’s Stone, Discovers Phosphorus, and prays for the successful Conclusion of his operation, as was the custom of the Ancient Chymical Astrologers" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alchemist_Discovering_Phosphorus#/media/File:Joseph_Wright_of_Derby_The_Alchemist.jpg

Comment: I also heard that, after the cloths ignited, the astrologer  dropped the muddy water on that and then put it in a plastic jar. She told me the jar was shaking afterward while it still producing smoke.